# Issue in installing marvel plugin elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-marvel

I am in the directory /usr/share/elasticsearch 
But after I run  "bin/plugin install" .I get the error  - bash: bin/plugin: No such file or directory. How can I install marvel.

Answer (score 2):

Though its a late reply, but may be other user found it useful.

- Looks like you have install Elasticseach-5* version, in this version    you don't have plugin.bat file. Instead you have to use    elasticsearch-plugin.bat file.  `elasticsearch-plugin install <plugin-name>`
- If you install for eg. version Elasticsearch-2.3.5 there you get
  plugin.bat file. and your can use `bin/plugin.bat install <plugin-name>`
- Note post elasticsearch-5* site plugins are not supported. See
  [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-site-plugins-with-elasticsearch-5-0) for more details.
- If server have some firewall which blocks downloading you could use offline way `plugin.bat install file:///C:/urowndirectory/urplugin.zip`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bin/plugin.bat install <plugin-name>
```

Comment: It didnt work.I have 4 files inside my  /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin folder. 
1) elasticsearch
2) elasticsearch.in.sh
3) elasticsearch-plugin
4) elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec

Comment: Ideally there should be a plugin.bat file in your bin folder. Make sure you are installing ES correctly.